# System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 2018-09-18T16:57:37Z

Tags: soql, batch, datetime

I'm getting Invalid date/time: 2018-09-18T16:57:37Z  in the developer console. please help me with this

```
DateTime dt = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-10);     
String formatedDt = dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.valueOf(formatedDt);
 system.debug('date  *****'+myDateTime);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to describe clearly which line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');` formats the date in a way that is incompatible with the `DateTime.valueOf()` method.

`DateTime.valueOf()` [expects](http://apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) the string to be formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and in the local timezone. Since your string isn't formatted that way, you're getting an error when that line runs.

To get the correct format you should update this line

`String formatedDt = dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');`

to this:

`String formatedDt = dt.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');`

Comment: Thanks @john towers than how  I will get this format  yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ from yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @Sairam I've updated the answer with what should be changed to produce the correct format.